# How to create ladder for 2d platformer?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, game-development

we are doing a simple 2d platform game, and there are difficulties with the stairs ._. The bottom line is that it is necessary that the character could climb on the ladder to stand on it, and by pressing the down arrow to descend. In order to do this, we used PlatformEffector2D at the platform with which the ladder touches at its highest point, and wrote a script that should change the rotationalOffset when the character touches the collider of this platform itself, depending on its current value (0 or 180) and clamped keys (up or down). Here is the code:

```
    private void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D col)
      {
        if (col.gameObject.name == "platform_ladder")
      {
        PlatformEffector2D pe = 
    col.gameObject.GetComponent<PlatformEffector2D>();
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow) && pe.rotationalOffset == 
      0)
        {
            pe.rotationalOffset = 180;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) && pe.rotationalOffset 
       == 180)
          {
            pe.rotationalOffset = 0;
          }
        }
     }
```

As a result, the character climbs the stairs, stands on it, but does not react to pressing the key down. If you step back and come back to make money then the script works, and the rotationoffset changes. However, then it is impossible to stand on the platform, and the character just climbs through it there and there. I give an example of recording from the screen (unfortunately it slows down the video, but the essence of what I wrote on it is visible)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ccUi0sqtVxFS1UAKE7QaQKvr3x4-7S8o

In any case, I will give the code for climbing the stairs; suddenly there is a mistake in it:

```
   /* CLimbing */

    raydistance = 0;
    RaycastHit2D hitinfo = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.up, raydistance, whatisLadder);

    if (hitinfo.collider != null)
    {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            isClimbing = true;

        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            isClimbing = false;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        isClimbing = false;
    }

    anim.SetBool("OnLadder", isClimbing);

    if (isClimbing && hitinfo.collider != null)
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.position.x, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * speed);
        // rb.gravityScale = 0;
        rb.isKinematic = true;
        anim.SetBool("Ground", true);
    else
    {
        rb.isKinematic = false;
        // rb.gravityScale = 3;
    }
```

We do not ask to write a solution code, but we ask you to explain the principle to us and send it in the right direction, thank you ^^

Comment: I actually did this for one of my games https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTJqtJgATR8 You can download the project files at  https://github.com/sean244/Braid-Clone

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add trigger colliders to the character and ladder gameobjects and increase the player's y position when holding up and in the trigger?

```
private Rigidbody rb;
[SerializeField]
private float ClimbingSpeed;

void Start(){
rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

Public void OnTriggerStay(Collider collider){
 if(collider.gameobject.tag == "Ladder" && input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)){
     rb.moveposition(
  transform.position.x, 
  transform.position.y + 1 * Time.DeltaTime * ClimbingSpeed, 
  transform.position.z
{
{
```